# Make changes in Doc, Docx file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docx, doc

User can upload a `.doc` or `.docx` file and the uploaded file will be opened in my ASP.NET MVC view for editing. User can add text in the file and when he/she is done with the changes, the file will be saved on server.

Comment: And what is your **question**?? This is just a wish list of features.... and close to a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772322/edit-pdf-document-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I want to achieve this and don't know where to start. Can you please help me with it? The main problem is to make changes in the doc, docx file in asp.net MVC view.

Comment: You need to research & find a suitable library - doing this full circle on your own is probably too demanding. There are quite a few open-source/free libraries, as well as paid libraries

Comment: Can you please suggest some of the free libraries for this purpose?

Comment: A quick Google search is your friend - try [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) or [FreeSpire.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html) or any of the [others listed here on Nuget](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/docx)

Comment: You can also try [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document), you can use any HTML editor with it in order to create an online DOC and DOCX editor.

Comment: Yes, I found it when looking for solutions but it's paid.